# Is there a formalised mathematics of sound?

Tags: calculus, continuity, computational-complexity, wave-equation

It's an odd question, because sound is so broad. But even more generally I mean to ask is there a mathematical branch which deals specifically with notes, chords, and symphonic complexity in a mereological way? Where notes are individual functions I suppose, and chords might be composites of these functions, or combinations of these functions.

Comment: Fourier analysis perhaps?

Comment: There was a course in my uni "music and mathematics", I believe we followed [this book](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~wright/Math109/00Book.pdf) by D.Wright, together with some others, but my old links are now dead.